# Howcan I change the visible name of a many2many field?

Tags: many-to-many, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I am using Odoo8.

I have two models: `x_items` and `project.task.work`.

I have a field called `name` and a custom field called `x_wo_ref` in the `project.task.work`.

I have a many2many field `x_item_wo` in the model `x_items` which is related with the model `project.task.work`.

Currently when I fill the field `x_item_wo`, the field `name` from `project.task.work` is showed.

How can I customise it in order to use the field `x_wo_ref` instead of the default field `name` for this many2many field?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the `_rec_name` attribute of the model. `_rec_name` takes as default the field `name` and if this does not exist it does not take anything unless you specify it. For instance if you need to see the field phone you must write:

`_rec_name = 'phone'`

In case you want a `_rec_name` depending on anything you need to change the function `name_get()`. You can see examples in other models.

Comment: The problem that the model is created using the odoo developer mode (settings -> model).. so is there any way to define the _rec_name for this model?

Comment: You must create a new custom module

Comment: Ok i will.. Thank you